# EmguCV: Get coordinates of pixels in a line between two points

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

So here's my goal: I want to stop at each pixel on a line and do some processing on those pixels. Currently i'm using EmguCV for my image processing library. In openCV there is a method called LineIterator which you can use to iterate through the pixel in a line. However, I haven't found a method similar to this in EmguCV which is where I am getting stuck.

Currently, I can get the pixel values of all the pixels on a line between two predefined points using the [Image.Sample](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/eaaf9cad-1fbc-73bb-b190-d216c4edf6f4.htm) method. For a grayscale image Image this returns a n-by-1 matrix with n being the number of pixels on that line. However, I am not able to get the coordinates of each pixel on that particular line corresponding to the pixel values in the n-by-1 matrix mentioned above. Hence, I am not able to do image processing on these pixels, even though I have their pixel values. Is there a way to do this on EmguCV?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I implemented the bresenham line algoritm for my own project
(converted to C# from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm))

```
    public static List<Point> GetBresenhamLine(Point p0, Point p1)
    {
        int x0 = p0.X;
        int y0 = p0.Y;
        int x1 = p1.X;
        int y1 = p1.Y;
        int dx = Math.Abs(x1 - x0);
        int dy = Math.Abs(y1 - y0);

        int sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
        int sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1;

        int err = dx - dy;

        var points = new List<Point>();

        while (true)
        {
            points.Add(new Point(x0, y0));
            if (x0 == x1 && y0 == y1) break;

            int e2 = 2 * err;
            if (e2 > -dy)
            {
                err = err - dy;
                x0 = x0 + sx;
            }
            if (e2 < dx)
            {
                err = err + dx;
                y0 = y0 + sy;
            }
        }

        return points;
    }
```

I implemented my own "Point" struct, but think it matches Emgu's.
I think this should take care of any special cases.

Comment: Thanks, I've made my own and it's more or less similar to your code.

Answer (score 0):

If (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are two end points.

```
(x1, y1) ___________________ (x2, y2)
```

then you can get intermediate points by

```
for (int i = x1, i < x2; i++)
{
 int x = i;
 int y = (y1 + (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) * (x - x1)))
 cout << "Points : " << x << " " << y << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This I think is the Bresenham's line algorithm. I was looking for some other solution within emguCV that may have already been built into the library but I have found none, so I guess I'll be using this.

The equation you posted works for lines with an absolute slope of less than 1 or in you case abs((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)) < 1. For the lines with larger slopes, you need to iterate through the y instead of the x to get a better line. Also, I think there needs to be a special case added for when the line is vertical or horizontal since, you would be dividing by 0 in vertical lines.

Comment: Yes this is Bresenham's algorithm,

Comment: This answer works only for horizontal lines. The accepted answer consider sampling in vertical direction too.